# For which values of $\alpha$ do the solutions approach zero as $t \to \infty$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification

Consider the family of differential equations below, where $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$.

$y''-4\alpha y'+3\alpha^2y=0$.
For which values of $\alpha$ do the solutions approach zero as $t$ approaches infinity?

**My attempt**

Using the characteristic polynomial we have $r^2-4\alpha r+3\alpha^2=0$.

Factoring by grouping gives $(r-\alpha)(r-3\alpha)=0$, so $r=\alpha,3\alpha$.

Because the characteristic polynomial has distinct real roots, it follows that $y_1(t)=e^{\alpha t}$ and $y_2(t)=e^{3\alpha t}$ form a fundamental set of solutions.

Thus the general solution is $y(t)=c_1e^{\alpha t}+c_2e^{3\alpha t}=span(e^{\alpha t},e^{3\alpha t})$.

$\therefore$ for $\alpha <0, \lim\limits_{t\to \infty} y(t)=0$

Is this correct?

Comment: Almost correct. Note that for $\alpha = 0$ the roots aren‘t distinct.

Comment: @martini makes sense. So $y_1(t)$ and $y_2(t)$ don't necessarily form a fundamental set of solutions for this differential equation, but they are still solutions to the original differential equation since any value of $r$ that is a root of the characteristic equation corresponds to a solution $y=e^{rt}$ of the original differential equation?

Comment: Also, the Wronskian of $y_1$ and $y_2$ is nonzero iff $\alpha \neq 0$. Now because the problem asks for which values of $\alpha$ do the solutions approach zero as t approaches infinity, then can we just take the limit of each of the two solutions separately and conclude that $\alpha$ must be negative?

Comment: Your solution is correct for $\alpha \ne 0$. Just consider $\lpha= 0$ separately. The equation is $y‘‘ = 0$ then.

Comment: In particular, your problem is that what you have shown is that the solutions are guaranteed to go to $0$ for $\alpha < 0$ and are guaranteed to not go to $0$ for $\alpha > 0$ (unless $y \equiv 0$, which is always a solution). But you have not settled whether $\alpha = 0$ should be included with the first group or the second.